# Solve for $x$ in $e^{2x}-21e^x+110=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, quadratics

What are the two solutions to this equation?
$$e^{2x}-21e^x+110=0$$
I'm stumped! Taking $\log$ of both sides doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Set $y=e^x$ and solve as a regular quadratic (since $e^{2x}=y^2$). Once you have $y$, take $x=ln(y)$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How about a u-substitution with $u=e^{x} $.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Write the equation as
$$(e^x)^2-21(e^x)+110=0$$
and solve for $e^x$. Then solve the resulting equations for $x$.

You can simply factor as
$$(e^x-10)(e^x-11)=0$$
and go from there.

So now you should be able to solve $ae^{2x}+be^x+c=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Set

$y=e^{x}$, so $y^{2}=e^{2x}$, and we had $e^{2x}-21e^{x}+110=0$

So:
$$y^{2}-21y+110=0$$

This is Quadratic Equation and if we solve this (for example with [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)), two values will be calculated for $y$:

$$y_{1}=10\\ y_{2}=11$$

At first we set $y=e^{x}$, so $x=ln(y),\ y>0$. $y_1$ and $y_2$ are positive ($y_1, y_1>0$) so there are two values for $x $, $x_1 $ and $ x_2$:

$$x_1 = \ln(y_1) = \ln(10)$$
$$x_2 = \ln(y_2) = \ln(11)$$